# Why can't I reference extension methods with internal visibility from my .cshtml pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, extension-methods, access-modifiers

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 default project (upgraded from 2.0 without using the new "default UI" facilities, as the plan is to customise the default views and controllers). I wanted to make the login status message when user is logged in address them by email address rather than name, so I defined this extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace MyAppNamespace
{
    internal static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions
    {
        public static string Email(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
            => claimsPrincipal.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "email").Value;
    }
}
```

and changed the relevant code in _LoginPartial.cshtml to read as follows:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Email()!</a>
```

This doesn't build:

```
Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml(11,102,11,107): error CS0122: 'ClaimsPrincipalExtensions.Email(ClaimsPrincipal)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

But the extension class and the .cshtml page belong to the same project. If I change the "internal" access modifier on the extension class to "public", then it builds and works as I would expect. Why can't I use "internal" here?

Comment: Could it be that, although they are part of the same project, as the view are dynamically compiled, they are actually in a different assembly?

Comment: Is controller also inside `MyAppNamespace` namespace?

Comment: @SeM - Unless I have misunderstood, the namespaces should not matter. "internal" restricts visibility to the assembly in which the type or member is defined. In all cases I have encountered, this is the same thing as restricting visibility to the project in which the type or member is defined. "internal" has nothing to say about namespaces.

Comment: @Hammerite Well.. yes you are right, internal modifier defines internal types or members, that are accessible only within files in the same assembly. Probably there is something to do with razor engine.

Comment: I think the problem is, that views are generating by `System.Web.Razor` (if I'm not mistaken) which is assembly by itself referenced to your assembly, so by marking your extension class internal, you will not be able to access it inside views and there is no other way to add any extension methods to external (existing) assemblies.

Comment: Extension methods are scoped to a namespace.  Whether they are `internal` or `public` is irrelevant.  You have to use `@using` statements in your razor views or add globally in the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file.

Comment: @Brad - As I stated in the question, it makes a difference whether the class containing the extension method is declared as internal or public (in the one case it fails to build, in the other case it builds). The access modifier is the only thing I need to change in order to effect this change in behaviour. This plainly contradicts your statement that "whether they are internal or public is irrelevant".

Answer (score 0):

Probably you View is not inside `MyAppNamespace` you should look into it. Try to change `internal` to `public` you extension class `ClaimsPrincipalExtensions`

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood, the namespaces should not matter. "internal" restricts visibility to the assembly in which the type or member is defined. In all cases I have encountered, this is the same thing as restricting visibility to the project in which the type or member is defined. "internal" has nothing to say about namespaces.

Comment: @Hammerite I explain incorrect. When I told about namespace `MyAppNamespace` I mean namespace as an assembly in this case.